# How is data stored across shards in clickhouse in cluster deployment?

Tags: data-warehouse, clickhouse

I wanted to know how is data stored across shards in clickhouse? Is the data divided across shards for a table? Or the data for a table is replicated across the shards? And do I have to specify distributed tables while using cluster mode? What happens to tables created without specifying distributed table? And can we create tables which use two engine types? Ex. ReplacingMergeTree and Distributed both

Answer (score 0):

I think you are conflating a few different concepts. Shards and replica are independent concept. You always have one shard. You can configure how many replica (the number of copies) to replicated for that particular shard.

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/architecture/horizontal-scaling#description